# Unable to Publish Website Directly From Visual Studio

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015, permissions, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to publish a simple web page to the path

`\\SERVERNAME\C$\inetpub\wwwroot\QCPage`

But I get this message when I try:

> Unable to create the Web site '\SERVERNAME\C$\inetpub\wwwroot\QCPage'.  The path '\SERVERNAME\C$\inetpub\wwwroot\QCPage' does not exist or you do not have access. The specified path is invalid.

I can confirm that the path definitely does exist, as I can navigate to it in file explorer.

This makes me think it must be a permissions issue. Now I am not logged in to my PC as a domain user of `SERVERNAME`, but I did enter some user credentials when navigatig to the folder in File Explorer, and that user has full access to the folder in question.

I also tried mapping the path to the `Z:` drive and publishing to `Z:\QCPage`, but with the same results.

Do I have to logged into my PC as a server user to publish from Visual Studio? If not, how can I pass the same credentials I provided in File Explorer to the Visual Studio publishing profile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by following these steps in Visual Studio:

- View
- Server Explorer
- Connect to Server
- Connect using a different user name...
- Here I entered the user credentials of the local server account which I was using to access the server through File Explorer
- In the `Computer` field I typed the name of the server, `SERVERNAME`
- After clicking `OK`, the server appeared in the Server Explorer list
- I am now able to publish the site directly to the server from Visual Studio

Comment: You save my life!